# Redirect index.php urls in Magento causes problems to backend

Tags: apache, .htaccess, magento, mod-rewrite

I needed to redirect all these urls

```
https://www.example.com/index.php/la-roche-posay-acqua-micellare-ultra-pelle-sensibile-100ml.html
```

To new non-index.php ones:

```
https://www.example.com/la-roche-posay-acqua-micellare-ultra-pelle-sensibile-100ml.html
```

I added this row in my `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteRule ^index.php/(.*)$ /$1 [R=301,NC,L]
```

(after `RewriteRule .* index.php [L]`)

Redirects work well, but this rule has blocked some functions in backend: system doesn't save any change in categories, products, etc.

How can I fix it?

Comment: "after `RewriteRule .* index.php [L]`" - The directive you added should go _before_ this directive, not after it. The order is important. As a general rule, redirects before rewrites.

Comment: @w3dk in this way, redirect doesn't work

Comment: If the pages you want to redirect end all with html you can do that :
`RewriteRule ^index.php/(.*)html$ /$1 [R=301,NC,L]`

Comment: sorry @adrien54 it doesn't work